# Yii2 - Count and sum not include of result of ActiveQuery

Tags: mysql, yii2

Basically I have a legacy query in mysql that I will be implement into ActiveRecord,

**Legacy Way, as expected**

```
SELECT 
  a.container_seal, 
  a.size ,
  count(a.size) as bundles,
  sum(a.piece) as pieces
FROM pipe a
WHERE a.outgoing_pipe_id IS NULL
GROUP by a.container_seal, a.size
ORDER by a.container DESC
```

**AR Way**

```
 $modelPipe = Pipe::find()

        ->select([
            "container_seal",
            "size",
            "count(size) as bundles",
            "sum(piece) as pieces"
        ])

        ->where(['outgoing_pipe_id' => NULL])
        ->groupBy(['container_seal', 'size'])
        ->orderBy(['container' => SORT_DESC])
        ->all();
```

But why, when I debug it,

```
  <pre>
     <?php
        print_r($modelPipe);
     ?>
  </pre>
```

**The count and sum is not into.**

```
Array
(
[0] => app\models\hanwa\Pipe Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [container_seal] => TEMU6099067/ EMCCSQ6566
                [size] => 15 x 35 x 0.85 x 6000
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [container_seal] => TEMU6099067/ EMCCSQ6566
                [size] => 15 x 35 x 0.85 x 6000
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => app\models\hanwa\Pipe Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [container_seal] => TEMU6099067/ EMCCSQ6566
                [size] => 35 x 35 x 0.75 x 6000
            )
```

Is it Yii2 have another way to use sum and count in case 'select' ?

Comment: please update your question and add  your Pipe model code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoudl add  the pubblic var for bundles and pieces in your pipe model
(for recive the result of query )

```
class Pipe extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
   public $bundles;
   public $pieces;
 ......
```

Comment: Yii2 Docs not to tell us like this.

Comment: The concept is taht you need  a  var for store result in active record  basec model .. so for db fields are automatically generatedc by framewrok but for others you must supply the according var name  ..

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#selecting-extra-fields